# Save new password hash in database after login

Tags: php, security, passwords, bcrypt, password-hash

Could it be a good idea to "re-hash" a password after every login and save the new hash into the database? Are there any pros and cons for this in terms of modern security standards?

Here a minimal code example in PHP:

```
function login(string $username, string $password): bool {
    // function arguments coming from $_POST
    $user = User::findByUsername($username);
    if($user) {
        if(password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
            // re-hash password ...
            $user->password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            //  ... and save it in database
            $user->save();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No - no need to rehash after every login. That is just "busy" work. I could say a lot more here, but it would just be words upon words about how hashes work and why rehashing is costly and unnecessary.

Comment: If you're worried about older hashes being leaked, why do you think this would help? The old ones would still be valid bcrypt hashes even if they weren't the same as the ones currently in the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Is there any further reading you could recommend why this particular case of rehashing after the login is unnecessary?

Comment: @iainn  I can imagine a case where someone got lucky with a rainbow table but still could be unable to login since the hash has changed in the meantime.

Comment: I could use a rainbow table to guess passwords, so it doesn't matter what the hash is. [Read this](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) especially the part about Batman. A bad password cannot be saved by a hash.

Comment: @LupusVagans How does changing the hash help with that though? The password is either valid or not, if they've somehow cracked it then it will work regardless of whether the hash has changed. If I've worked out that your password is **abc123**, then it doesn't make a difference if you've got `$2y$10$cm33gzHV/jLmNGcSxNO4zOHvn.eQ6PlWXlxDxyY42gOXADn0DKX9C` or `$2y$10$uG2Kudc.bmuJP0PFy9l0KOl88cz795feHqEML3zGAwIp290ySflZa` in your database, I can still log in.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: You got a point there. If the password is leaked the hash does not matter. Thanks for helping me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rehashing the password after each successful login does not increase security.

If the function `password_hash()` would use a fix global salt, the hash would look exactly the same for the same password. So an attacker would not even notice any difference in the database.

Though, the function `password_hash()` *will* generate a long enough unique salt if used properly, and several hashes of the same password with different salts will not make brute-forcing easier.

So while rehashing does not weaken security, it does not help in any way either, it is better to use the time to increase the cost factor.

Comment: Brute force with 2 hashes? Nope. Hashes are not reversible, especially with random salts. Even without, having two hashes does not increase the odds of an attacker being able to crack the hash.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Yes that's more or less what I wrote. If there wasn't a salt, and the attacker brute-forces with a dictionary, one of the hashes is found earlier and therefore decreases time for brute-forcing. Didn't say it is possible to crack the hash, but it is a disadvantage.

Comment: No, it's not. Given the OP is using `password_hash()` which provides random salts there is no decrease in security. There is a lot of evidence that brute-forcing against hashes gives no clue about other hashes, even without salts. I can brute force a dictionary against a hash all day long and if I get one match it does not make it easier for me to match the other hashes. Let's say you find a matching hash for the password 'rainbow' (adgf654543) and another matching hash for the password 'rainbow' (ja7634jhh42) - can you use the 2 hashes to determine the passwords of other hashes?

Comment: Furthermore could you use the two hashes to locate other users who used 'rainbow' as their password?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Well, you are correct. If a unique salt is used, this mitigates the problem (as I wrote). If the application (wrongly) used a global salt, which is possible, it would result in the exact same hash, so the attacker would not have two different hashes of the same password. Will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to rehash your user's password every time they login. It doesn't improve your security whatsoever.